# Receiving SettingWithCopyWarning. Is it safe to proceed?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, chained-assignment

I am trying to replace the column `'let'` in the DataFrame `london`(which is a copy of another `no_eco`) with rows that only contain the strings in the `contains()` method. The code is as follows:

```
london = no_eco
london.loc[:,'let'] = london.loc[:,'let'].str.contains('E' or 'D' or 'F' or 'G' or 'H' or 'I' or 'J')
london.loc[:,'let'] = london.loc[:,'let'][london.loc[:,'let']]
london = london.dropna(subset = ['let'])
print(london)
```

The code works and I have dropped the rows where the strings are not met however I receive the following warning:

```
C:\Users\gerardchurch\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py:543: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas- docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
```

and when looking at the documentation, I still can't understand what I am doing wrong.

Is this okay to continue using variable `london` or will I encounter problems in the future?

Thanks.

Comment: Change `london.loc[:,'distId'][london.loc[:,'distId']]` to `london.loc[london.loc[:,'distId'],'distId']` and the warning will go away. Not sure if in this case it's particularly harmful because you're doing it on the RHS of the assignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues with your code:

1. `london = no_eco` doesn't assign a *copy* to `london`. Be explicit: `london = no_eco.copy()`.
2. [`pd.Series.str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) supports regex by default, so use `str.contains('E|D|F|G|H|I|J|')`.
3. Your logic is confused. You first replace an `object` dtype series with a Boolean series, then you assign to it a subset indexed by itself, then use `dropna`, which is designed for *null* values.

Instead, just construct a Boolean series and use [`pd.DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with Boolean indexing:

```
london = no_eco.copy()
london = london.loc[london['let'].str.contains('E|D|F|G|H|I|J|')]
```

For this particular case, you can use `pd.DataFrame.__getitem__` (`df[]` syntax) directly:

```
london = no_eco.copy()
london = london[london['let'].str.contains('E|D|F|G|H|I|J|')]
```